# Extract nodes X Y Z from lines

Tags: qgis, xyz

In QGis 2.18.3

The Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes tool will generate a point layer shapefile with points at each vertex of each line.

But each point in layer does not have the z coordinate, only x and y.

How can i extract nodes with (X Y Z) from lines?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include what software you are using.

Comment: Are you sure your features have a Z value?  I assume you mean the Extract Vertices tool and this will produce a Point(z) feature if the input line has z values too.  I have just tested it to be certain and can confirm this is the case.

Comment: There are four different tools in the toolbox which achieve what you need, provided the lines have any values attached to them.

Comment: You can check your feature with the  "Identify Features" tool which looks like a blue circle with an "i" and an arrow. [ Ctl+Shift+ i  ]  Click your feature and in the lower right of the screen will be the ** Identify Results **  You can expand the **Derived** properties and look at the "Z" value.